# Android / Java: For loop preventing array from being called

Tags: java, android, button, for-loop

I am making a 3x3 grid type application, and I want to recall the button pressed to change it by adding a for loop. However, I get the exception "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3" because the for loop is weird. Could anyone figure out this for me? I am new to java and programming in general.

Code:

```
public int j = 1;
public int i = 1;
public final int[][] buttons = new int[][] {
        {R.id.top_left_button, R.id.top_center_button, R.id.top_right_button},
        {R.id.left_button, R.id.center_button, R.id.right_button},
        {R.id.bottom_left_button, R.id.bottom_center_button, R.id.bottom_right_button}};
private Button lastButton;

public void setPlayer(Button button, int x, int y){
    button.setText("!");
    lastButton = (Button)findViewById(buttons[x][y]);
    lastButton.setText(" ");
    lastButton = button;
}
@Override


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);


    ctx = this;

    final GameEngine game = new GameEngine();
    lastButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.center_button);
    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
            final Button button = (Button)findViewById(buttons[i][j]);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button b = (Button)v;
                    int x = i;
                    int y = j;
                    setPlayer(b, x , y);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try this public final int[][] buttons = new int[3][3] now assign id's to array .

Comment: @sonukumar: What difference would it make?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 check McGee answer for more details .

Comment: I have read that answer but your comment says something different. Putting size is not necessary when you are assigning value right then

Answer (score 3):

The question you need to ask is: what are the values of `i` and `j` *when the button is clicked*?

The answer for `i` is: `buttons.length.` Because that's the value you left `i` at when you left the loop.

This should work:

```
for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        final int iCopy = i;  
        for (j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
            final Button button = (Button)findViewById(buttons[i][j]);
            final int jCopy = j;
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button b = (Button)v;
                    int x = iCopy;
                    int y = jCopy;
                    setPlayer(b, x , y);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The reason this will work is, because of the scoping, you are creating a new instance of `iCopy` with each outer iteration, and a new instance of `jCopy` with each inner iteration. Each anonymous `OnClickListener` implementation will now be using the appropriate copies.

Comment: Good catch! However, IMO, a better solution is to declare i and j as local variable unless the value of i and j is used later, which I very much doubt

Answer (score 1):

You should declare and initialize your array like this:

```
public final int[][] buttons = {
        {R.id.top_left_button, R.id.top_center_button, R.id.top_right_button},
        {R.id.left_button, R.id.center_button, R.id.right_button},
        {R.id.bottom_left_button, R.id.bottom_center_button, R.id.bottom_right_button}};
```

In your loops you can just initalize new i and j variables like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

No need to declare them at the top of your activity.